# How to create a twisted spiral tunnel?

Tags: modeling, shaders, procedural

I need to to create a twisted tunnel. Example:
[image: picture]

Though the stripes should have volume since the tunnel is the inner side of spiraled **marshmallow tubes**. Example:
[image]

I started adding a screw modifier to a plane which looked promising from from the tutorial, though not on the inside:
[image: picture]

Any ideas or should I try to start with a bended cone, add a twisted color ramp & bump?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**The hard way**

But the way you can use to pour sugarlicious material on.

As usual we'll begin with a simple vertex. Easiest way is to add a cube, or plane, and go into edit mode, vertex select mode, select all with <kbd>A</kbd> then Right Click > Merge > At Center.

[image]

Add a *Displace* modifier set to X, lower the *midlevel* and increase the strength. Don't mind the vertex group, you don't need it.

[image]

Add a *Screw* modifier, increase the *screw*, *iterations* and *steps* (viewport and render)

[image]

Let's give it some thickness ! First add another screw, but set the *steps* to 1.

[image]

*How to create a noodle*. Don't worry about the wonky shading just yet.

[image]

Add a *Bevel* modifier set to angle and crank up the width. Add a Weld to remove the seam in the middle.

[image]

The tricky part. Add an empty, set it as the object offset in a new array modifier. Now we drive the empty rotation so that the result is always equally separated.

[image]

Set the array count to 10.

[image]

Add a *Bezier curve*, scale it. Add a *Curve* modifier to the other object, and set the curve as the target.

[image]

Let's shade this masterpiece ! (Easy part)

[image]

What the ?? Everything's white !

[image]

Let me show you the simplest magic trick in the book. *Offset UV* in the *Array* modifier.

[image]

Final result :

[image]

I'll let you play with the settings, not all the fun for me :)

[image]

Comment: Hmmm,,,, how did I know whose answer this was, way before I reached the bottom?

Comment: I'm probably breaking rules here, heck I don't care: Thank you, thank you, thank you so much @Gorgious

Comment: @412p9wej Sure by SE's rules you are technically not supposed to leave a comment like that (maybe). It very well might get deleted. But Gorgious has already seen it. The comment has served its purpose. I too have thanked the authors of particularity helpful answers. As long as you don't replace up voting with a thanks comment, I have no problem with saying thanks *in a comment*.

Answer (score 11):

In my opinion there is no need to create the actual geometry, since you may achieve the same effect (more or less) with normals and displacement (if you are using cycles microdisplacement will do the trick).

So I would start with a typical cylinder and I would use a seamless texture with stripes.

[image]

The trick is simply to rotate the texture, for few degrees
[image]

Just keep always in mind that there must be always a proper ratio between the rotation (degrees) and the thickness or the count of the stripes.

[image]

Comment: How have you got the rotation there? Have you manipulated the UV map to rotate the faces? Also, please explain why the Checker Texture.... surely that will produce edges when it gets to the next row (or, presumably, the Scale settings are avoiding that, to a certain point. How do you calculate the angle to use to make it seamless or is it just 'by sight'?

Comment: For the rotation/manipulation I am using the mapping node (there is no need to alter/edit the UVs of the object). 
Mapping node provides all the basic transformation you need to change a texture, which in this case is a checker.
So what I did was to shrink as much as it was needed the Y scale and raise the X. I could probably use a gradient with a ramp if I was looking for smooth "edges" in my texture.
Regarding the angle it is adjusted intuitively.
Try to replicate it and play a bit so you can understand how it behaves.

Comment: Oh, I see - because the Rotation applies before the Scale it's already rotated in relation to the 'straight' UV mapping and that's where the twist comes from. Nice solution (just need to be careful it doesn't get to far along the texture.

Comment: cnisidis and @RichSedman I've been trying to automate this, and can't get the numbers to make any sense.You want to rotate or shear the rectangular UV space so the phase at Y=1 is the same as the phase at Y=0, and the rectangle can be rolled into a tube with the edges matching. Tried with a shear, too, but parameter that works is always slightly off the one I would expect.. it would be nice not to have to eyeball it.

Answer (score 9):

I would use a *Bezier Curve*, it's typically easier to create tunnel-like objects.

In the *Object data* properties, add a bit of depth to create the tunnel. Increase the preview resolution (number of subdivisions between each control point) and the bevel resolution.

[image]

Add a material, go in to the *Shader Editor*. The curves come in auto-UV unwrapped so we will be using the UV coordinates. Add a wave texture, and tweak the settings as you see fit. I used a *Bright / Contrast* node to incrase the contrast, you can also use a *Color Ramp*. Next for the bumpiness, I added a *Math* node set to *Ping-Pong*, at half value, so the light will reflect on dark rings as well as on bright rings. I added a *RGB Curves* node and smoothed the values, and plugged that into a *Bump* node, and finally into the *Normal* input of the Principled BSDF.

A little bit of distortion in the Wave texture is nice, but it add a visible seam in the texture.

[image]

Result :

[image]

To get the twirly effect, we will have to play a bit with the coordinates. Thankfully it is not too hard since the UVs are nicely mapped to to body of the curve. We will use the Y coordinate to offset the wave, creating the twirl.

First change the wave texture to be along the Y axis. We will offset the Y coordinate by a multiple of the X coordinate. You can play with it. I recommend starting at a low multiple and working your way up, else you won't see much happening.

The nodes :

[image]

Result :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. If I may say, the black part should be one stripe instead of many rings. Is that possible?

Comment: @412p9wej I see, I edited the answer, is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: Mesmerizingly  good.

Comment: @Gorgious Outstanding :) I'll pour liquid and put licorice into that tunnel. I will need geometry in order to have correct interplay between all objects don't I? If so, I will gladly edit my question and emphasize on geometry