# How to modify each current's material of a twirl

Tags: modeling, shaders

I need to change this:
[image]
to this:
[image: picture]

The twirled tunnel was sophistically [crafted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/212162/99884)
from multiple properties, now I need to apply a unique coloured marshmallow material to each current (will reduce to 5 currents)

File download:

[image]

Comment: This might answer the question. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200469/randomized-color-with-array-modifier Instead of setting a UV offset of 1, set a very low amount so each subsequent array item gets a different color after the White Noise node

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a *ColorRamp* to create the pattern.

The *Modulo* and *Divide* nodes control the number of Color segments (5 in this example).

Note: You can only use up to 10 segments (you're limited by the Array modifier).

[image]